# SQL fetch svn revision

Tags: sql, svn

I want to add to db revision of script when it's used. Ie. I have test.sql file that is under svn, and each time I execute this script sql will fetch current revision and store in db.
I didn't find any solution for this for now.
Thanks

Comment: you can add an insert statement into you `test.SQL` where you insert a `$Revision: $` value. that value is changed by  commit in svn.

Comment: I know how to insert value, but I don't know how to fetch it from subversion, I couldn't find any information does svn:keyword is available for sql

Comment: if you put this `$Revision: $` in your script, after commit you will get a value like `$Revision: 123245648$` after the next commit the value will be chnaged.

Comment: ok, thanks I'll check this